# Grepping entire system but dodging process files and the like

Tags: grep

I have so many systems I need to do and I find it really impractical for me to grep everything/folders individually.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more elegant solutions to find what you're looking for than trying to grep everything in a filesystem, but you could use `find` to help and build a list of places to exclude like

```
find / \( -path /proc -o -path /<other> \) -prune -o -type f -exec grep -H "pattern" {} +
```

or something like that.  It sure feels like there may be a better way to solve the problem of finding what you're looking for than this though.

Update:  Based on comment from @lcd047 I added a flag to get grep to show you where it was matching stuff and `+` to make the exec part of find more efficient

Comment: You're close.  Try this instead: `find / \( -path /proc -o -path /<other> \) -prune -o -type f -exec grep "pattern" {} /dev/null +`.  The `+` means you'll run `grep` against groups of files rather than every single time a file is found; `/dev/null` makes sure `grep` prints the filename even when searching a single file.  Alternatively: `find / \( -path /proc -o -path /<other> \) -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "pattern" /dev/null`.

Comment: I should use the `+`, but why not just use the `-H` flag to grep instead of including `/dev/null`?

Comment: @lcd047 Another reason to use the `-H` flag is that, at least in POSIX, the `/dev/null` would negate much of the advantage of the `+` I think.  I think `+` is only special when it follows `{}` which it would not do in your example, though perhaps some implementations would be more efficient there nonetheless

Comment: Right, it should be `... -exec grep "pattern" /dev/null {} +`.  As for `-H`, some `grep(1)` implementations might not have it, while the `/dev/null` trick should work everywhere. _shrug_